# Webpack/Babel ES6 error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am very new to ES6 so forgive me if this a duplicate question. As the title states I'm currently receiving the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Obviously the object Person has not been successfully imported for use in the `app.js` file.

I've looked at example code across the web however still not working. I suspect its to do with the `webpack.config.js` settings.

I have also tried using `let person = require("./modules/Person");` but it does not work.

Please any ideas? They'll be much appreciated.

I've provide code excerpts below:

**src/js/modules/person.js**

```
class Person {

    constructor(name, jobtitle, sex){
        this.name = name;
        this.jobtitle = jobtitle;
        this.message = document.getElementById("message").html;
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    Greet(){
        console.log("Hello, my name is "+ this.name + " and i am a " + sex);
    }

    EchoOccupation(){
        console.log("I am a "+ this.jobtitle);
    }

    EchoMessage(){
        console.log("The message is "+ this.message);
    }
}

module.exports = Person;
```

**src/js/app.js**

```
import { Person } from './modules/person';

let vic = new Person("Fred", "Web Developer", "male");
vic.Greet();
vic.EchoOccupation("Web Developer");
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require("path"),
    watchBabel = require("watch-babel"),
    srcJsDir = "./src/js/",
    srcDestJsDir = "dist/assets/js/",
    options = { glob: "src/*.js" },
    watcher = watchBabel(srcJsDir, srcDestJsDir, options);

watcher.on("ready", function() { 
    console.log("ready"); 
}).on("success", function(filepath) {
    console.log("Transpiled ", filepath);
}).on("failure", function(filepath, e) {
    console.log("Failed to transpile", filepath, "(Error: ", e);
}).on("delete", function(filepath) {
    console.log("Deleted file", filepath);
});

module.exports = {

    entry: [srcJsDir + "/app.js"],
    output:  {
        path: srcDestJsDir,
        filename: "app.js"
    },
    watch: true,
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 8000
    },
    module: {
        loader : [
            { 
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: "/node_modules/",
                loaders: ['babel', 'watch-babel'],
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015'],
                    plugins: ['babel-plugin-uglify']
                } 
            },
        ]
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/')
    }
};
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>im loving es6</title>
    <link href="/src/css/frameworks/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body> 
    <header></header>
    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <article>
                        <section> 
                            <div id="app"></div>
                            <div id="message">Hello this is my message!</div>
                        </section>
                        <aside></aside>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer></footer>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/assets/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For your immediate problem, it seems relatively clear that you want to write something like: 

var Person = require('./modules/person');

rather than using "import".  That would be a reason for the syntax error.

I can't help you with your Webpack config.  Ah yes, you see, web browsers generally do not understand the new "import" syntax.

Comment: Thanks that worked!! Still do not get it... I would have thought Webpack would "transpile" or convert the "import" keyword like it does "let". Plus I attempted "let person = require("./modules/Person");" as well, probably at that point I was facing another error (a few I can see now after posting) but did not realise due to frustration.

Comment: Babel can indeed convert imports like that, but note that web browsers, e.g. recent Chrome, do understand other ES6 syntax such as "let". It looks to me like the errant script is running as-is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error occurs because the module exported from `person.js` does not have a `Person` property.

You can fix this by making three changes:

**src/js/modules/person.js**

```
class Person {
  ...
}

// Set the Person class as the object exported from this module
export default Person;
```

**src/js/app.js**

```
// Import the Person class
import Person from './modules/person';
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
...
module: {
  // Rename the 'loader' property to 'loaders'
  loaders: [
    ...
  ]
}
```

You'll find more information on `import` here: [ES6 import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: Chris P and gnerkus are both right, there were two critical errors in the webpack.config.js. Updating "loader:[ ]" to "loaders:[ ]" and removed "plugins: ['babel-plugin-uglify']" fixed the problem. Thanks guys, cant help but be embarrassed, looking back at the question, will get there, eventually.